# cartesian product of a power set with a set

Tags: set, cartesian-product, powerset, set-theory

how to explicitly write the cartesian product of a power set with another set.

eg: P({a,b})x{a,b}

Now P({a,b}) = {{},{a},{b},{a,b}}

so i need to know {{},{a},{b},{a,b}}x{a,b}

Answer (score 2):

Let `X` be a a set.  The power set of `X` is defined to be

```
P(X) := { S | S ⊆ X }
```

Let `X` and `Y` be sets.  The product `X × Y` is defined to be

```
X × Y := { (x,y) | x ∈ X, y ∈ Y }
```

---

Now let `X` and `Y` be sets.  We will describe the Cartesian product of the power set of `X` with `Y`:

```
P(X) × Y = { (S,y) | S ∈ P(X), y ∈ Y }
```

But `S ∈ P(X)` if and only if `S ⊆ X`.  This allows us to rewrite our product as

```
P(X) × Y = { (S,y) | S ⊆ X, y ∈ Y }
```

In other words, `P(X) × Y` consists of ordered pairs such that the first coordinate is some subset of `X` and the second coordinate is an element of `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your example is not consistent with your question:

You ask "how to explicitly write the cartesian product of a power set with **another** set?", and then you give the example of P({a,b})x{a,b}, which is the cartesian product of a power set with **the same** set, namely {a,b}.

2. For your example, as you said you have:

P({a,b}) = {{},{a},{b},{a,b}}

Then recall the definition of the cartesian product of two sets:

E x F = {(e,f), e in E, f in F}

Then by applying this definition:

P({a,b}) x {a,b} = {{},{a},{b},{a,b}} x {a,b}
                 = {({}, a), ({}, b), ({a}, a), ({a}, b), ({b}, a), ({b}, b), ({a,b}, a), ({a,b}, b)}

However, it is very unlikely that this kind of property would be useful in any concrete case or even theoretical theorem, because we almost never meet cases where {a} and a are treated "equally" (I mean, on the same "level" of sets), although it is absolutely correct from a mathematical point of view.